# Using Jquery functionality inside angularjs controllers is not updating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a angular application where i wrote some jquery selectors inside the angular controller and inside the jquery code i am trying to use ng-model element like below

```
    app.controller('forgotpasswordController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.check=function (elem) {
    if ($(elem).find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('name') == "recoveryQue") {
                    debugger;
    if($scope.Password==""||$scope.Password==undefined)
    {
        $scope.passwordResetModel.failuremessage = "Enter New Password.";
        return;    
    }
                    $scope.resetForgotPwd(function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            $(elem).toggleClass('disabled');
                            $(elem).find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('data-original-title', 'Password Recovery Questions Saved.');
                            $('.active').toggleClass('active')
                            $('#' + $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('aria-controls')).toggleClass('active');
                            $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
                        }
                    })
                }
}
    ]});
```

In the above code if call the `$scope.check()` without giving a value to `$scope.Password`, then the if condition is being satisfied and failuremessage value is getting set. but i can't see the failuremessage in the UI.

But if i do any operation like entering some text in any of the textbox in the form then failuremessage is getting populated on the UI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is `elem`? Where your `check` function called?

Comment: $elem is angular selector while you are applyinh jquery functions. Instead you may use jquery syntax to manipulte dom inside angular controller...the only change needed is to pick jquery selector not elem

Comment: @Andrey `elem` is my function argument. i have changed my question

Comment: @Nishith $elem is angular selector but i have never used $elem in my code..i am using like $(elem). so i think it won't create any problem.

Comment: Ok , I got it.. So in that case did you tried $(""+elem+"") , so that selector may pic it correctly

Comment: @Nishith I don't have any problem with the $(elem) selector...the problem is with setting a model variable..at `$scope.passwordResetModel.failuremessage = "Enter New Password."; `

Comment: You need to inform angularjs about your modifications by adding $scope.$apply() after changing the value  of your variable